# Jquery .on(click) looking for trigger

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

i have a background video from youtube api, 
but I can not start with sound. I did the test with .trigger  & .click  but it does not work. 
Do you have any idea what I can do?

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {   
  $('.sound').on('click', function(){
    $('#video-foreground').toggleClass('mute');
    $('.volume-icon').toggleClass('fa-volume-up', 'fa-volume-off');
    if($('#video-foreground').hasClass('mute')){
      player.mute();
    } else {
      player.unMute();
    }
  });
});


  $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.sound').click(); 


  });
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, you would have to initialize the player via api and pass an `onReady` Event Handler as an argument.

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.mute();
    player.playVideo();
}

$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    $('.sound').on('click', function(){
        $('#video-foreground').toggleClass('mute');
        $('.volume-icon').toggleClass('fa-volume-up', 'fa-volume-off');
        if ($('#video-foreground').hasClass('mute')){
            player.mute();
        } else {
            player.unMute();
        }
    });
});
```

where `ytplayer` is the iframe `id`

Answer (score 0):

Complete Script.
when it starts with sound it marks error. 
it is necessary to start in mute and activate it already working,  can activate it manually, but the idea is to activate it automatically

```
<script >var player; 

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('video-foreground', {
    videoId: 'bz8ko0wroJQ', // YouTube Video ID
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,       
      controls: 0,        
      showinfo: 0,       
     rel:0,
      modestbranding: 1,  
      loop: 1,            
      fs: 0,              
      cc_load_policy: 0, 
      iv_load_policy: 3,  
      autohide: 0,         
      playlist: 'PLR5MgzxY6DoGXL77i0as2_rKS3aEDcx_R'
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onready1,
      'onStateChange': onchange2
      }

  });
}

 function onready1(e) {   
        e.target.mute();

}

 function onchange2(e) {   
        if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            player.playVideo(); 
        }
 }

$(document).ready(function(e) {   
  $('.sound').on('click', function(){
    $('#video-foreground').toggleClass('mute');
    $('.volume-icon').toggleClass('fa-volume-up', 'fa-volume-off');
    if($('#video-foreground').hasClass('mute')){
      player.mute();
    } else {
      player.unMute();
    }
  });
});

</script>
```